# Change Wordpress Post Title Placeholder

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm Creating a custom post type and want to manipulate the placeholder text within the title field of the Create New Post section.

Requirements: 
 - It can only be for one specific post type, not for all posts.
 - It cannot reflect the name of the post type, it must be completely custom text.
 - It does not have to be editable from the wordpress admin section, the custom text can be placed  within the function in the functions.php file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can place this snippet in your functions.php

```
function change_default_title( $title ){

$screen = get_current_screen();

if ( 'your_custom_post_type' == $screen->post_type ){
$title = 'Your custom placeholder text';
}

return $title;
}

add_filter( 'enter_title_here', 'change_default_title' );
```

That should change the titel.

found on: https://gist.github.com/FStop/3094617

Answer (score 1):

You can also used this for multiple post types

```
add_filter('enter_title_here', 'my_title_place_holder' , 20 , 2 );
    function my_title_place_holder($title , $post){
        // For Activities
    if( $post->post_type == 'activities' ){
        $my_title = "Activity Name";
                return $my_title;
    }
        // For Instructors
    elseif( $post->post_type == 'instructors' ){
            $my_title = "Instructor Name";
                return $my_title;
    }

    return $title;
        }
```